# unable to run VMware workstation pro14 on windows 10

Tags: windows, vmware-workstation

I have tried to install workstation pro 14 on my windows 10. I disabled windows defender antivirus before running the setup as an administrator and I noticed that but I keep getting 2 services not running

[image]

When I am trying to start the VMware USB Arbitration Service I get

[image]

When I am trying to start the Vmware workstation server  Service I get

[image]

can anyone help me to resolve this issue ?

here is my systeminfo details

```
Host Name:                 XXXXXXXX
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.16299 N/A Build 16299
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
Registered Owner:          Shimon
Registered Organization:
Product ID:                

System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7 GenuineIntel ~3300 Mhz
BIOS Version:              American Megatrends Inc. V3.6, 9/29/2013
Windows Directory:         C:\WINDOWS
System Directory:          C:\WINDOWS\system32
Boot Device:               \Device\HarddiskVolume1
System Locale:             en-us;English (United States)
Input Locale:              en-us;English (United States)
Time Zone:                 (UTC+02:00) Jerusalem
Total Physical Memory:     16,336 MB
Available Physical Memory: 12,631 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  18,768 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 14,126 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    4,642 MB
Page File Location(s):     C:\pagefile.sys
Domain:                    WORKGROUP
Logon Server:              \\DESKTOP-5RJ4LCI
Hotfix(s):                 9 Hotfix(s) Installed.
                           [01]: KB4055237
                           [02]: KB4055994
                           [03]: KB4078408
                           [04]: KB4094276
                           [05]: KB4103729
                           [06]: KB4132650
                           [07]: KB4134661
                           [08]: KB4287903
                           [09]: KB4284819
Network Card(s):           3 NIC(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
                                 Connection Name: Ethernet
                                 DHCP Enabled:    Yes
                                 DHCP Server:     
                                 IP address(es)
                                 [01]: 
                                 [02]: 
                           [02]: VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
                                 Connection Name: VMware Network Adapter VMnet1
                                 DHCP Enabled:    Yes
                                 DHCP Server:     
                                 IP address(es)
                                 [01]: 192.168.30.1
                                 [02]: fe80::15b1:e43f:207e:baa
                           [03]: VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
                                 Connection Name: VMware Network Adapter VMnet8
                                 DHCP Enabled:    Yes
                                 DHCP Server:     
                                 IP address(es)
                                 [01]: 
                                 [02]: 
Hyper-V Requirements:      VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
                           Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes
                           Second Level Address Translation: Yes
                           Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes
```

Comment: First uninstall Hyper-V, then verify Core Isolation is disabled, then VMWare Workstation will work.  Make sure the dependency services have been started.  Disabling Windows Defender shouldn’t be necessary

Comment: any one has some comments ? I could really use your help

Comment: Did not see you comment Ramhound. Thanks a LOT. I am going to uninstall Hyper-V. What do u mean by disable Core Isolation ? how do I do it ?

Comment: Hi, When I wnet to uninstall Hyper-V I realized that it is already unchecked and it was in this status when I tried to run the vmware. Amy comments ?

Comment: Core Isolation, specifically Memory integrity, is a feature of 1803.

Comment: As I noted 1. Hyper-V is not checked on my windows and core isolation and off. And I still cannot get these 2 services to run :-(. Any suggestion. BTW, I really appreciate your support. Thanks

Comment: So have you made sure the Core Isolation memory integrity isn't enabled?

Comment: so I thought I answered you but for some reasons it does not appear in the conversation.I have screen shots of the configuration and the error message I received when I tried to run the image. How do I attach those images to my comment ? But to make it short, YES I made sure the Core Isolation was off

Comment: If you submitted a comment, it was likely flagged, by somebody else.  I didn't return to this question since I submitted my comment on June 20th.

Comment: so where do I go from here. very strange that I cannot seem to run the software. I did everything you suggested and in vain. I tried runnning uninstall and install repair etc... and nothing seems to be working and I do not believe it cannot work. Am I missing a service that should be thee and is not (look above at all the services that vmware runs). Thanks for very quick response

Answer (score 0):

> When I am trying to start the Vmware workstation server Service I get
>
> [image]

You are getting this error because one of the services, the Workstation Server service depends on, is unable to start.  If I were to hazard a guess, the VMWare USB Arbitration Service, is that service.

> When I am trying to start the VMware USB Arbitration Service I get
>
> [image]

The reason you are getting this error is that your system is missing required files.

> Resolution:
>
> 1. Launch a command prompt on the host machine using an Administrator account. For more information, see the Microsoft TechNet article Start
>      a command prompt as an administrator.
> 2. Run this command:
>
> net start hcmon
>
> 3. Open the Windows service console and start the service manually.
>
> To install the hcmon service manually:
>
> 1. Launch a command prompt on the host machine using an Administrator account.
> 2. Run this command:
>
>    - In a 32-bit host operating system:
>
> "C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Workstation\vnetlib.exe" -- install
>   hcmon
>
> - In a 64-bit host operating system:
>
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\vnetlib64.exe" --
>   install hcmon
>
> 3. Open the Windows service console and start the service manually. The service should now start successfully.
>
> If the issue persists even after trying the preceding steps,
>   reinstall/repair VMware Workstation as a user with Administrative
>   rights on the Windows host.

[VMware USB Arbitration service fails to start in VMware Workstation (2043656)](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2043656)

Comment: The VMware log file has all the information needed to confirm that, the service that is indeed blocking the VMWare Workstation Server service, is indeed `VMWare USB Arbitration Service`